# Angular12 - Passing function to the component and handling result

Tags: javascript, angular, angular12

I would like to create a common component for button which executes method, and then handles the result INSIDE child component. As I understand **@Output** is oneway binding, so I cannot process result of passed function, so I need to use **@Input**.

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
<my-button (action) = "exampleAction" [showConfirmation]="true">Reload</my-button>
```

But With **@Input** I need to pass functions to my component using **.bind(this)** and this is not elegant way. It looks like that:

```
<my-button (action) = "exampleAction.bind(this)" [showConfirmation]="true">Reload</my-button>
```

Is there any way (maybe using observables) to create simple, nice buton component which takes a method, block itself, processing method and handling it's result?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can combine output and input to get a two way binding.
take a look to this  [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c1hzc7?)

```
<hello (action)="increment()" [resultAvailable]="resultAvailable"></hello>
```

Comment: This is quite good approach